# How to do this query with Laravel query builder by more mysql and php

Tags: laravel

'm trying to run this query in Laravel, and would like to do it with the query and php builder, so I can use the paginate() method. But I can't seem to figure out how to get this subquery going.

```
    foreach ($array AS &$value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)==3)
        $l3[]="'".$value."'";
        else 
        $l4[]="'".$value."'";
        $valuex[]=$value;
    }
    if ($l4  && $l3)
    $where.="AND (left(field,3) IN (".join(", ",$l3).") || left(field,4) IN (".join(", ",$l4)."))";
    else if ($l3)
    $where.="AND (left(field,3) IN (".join(", ",$l3)."))";
    else 
    $where.="AND (left(field,4) IN (".join(", ",$l4)."))";
$sql=query("SELECT * FROM simso where field $where");
```

I want to convert to laravel .

```
Simplemodel::where(..........
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide better indication of what the query is trying to achieve. I would look at optimising your query first (it looks incredibly complex for what it might be trying to do) and then working out how to apply it to Eloquent.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Simplemodel::whereRaw($where)->get();`